# accessing a class member from another class in c++

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, exception

I am trying to access the member of a class declared in another class as an attribute.

The project class has a workArea that is also a class defined in the project.h.

I instanciate a project in the main, and then I send it to the mainWindow through its constructor. Once in the mainWindow constructor I try to access project->lat that works fine, but project->workArea->latInf crashes.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**project.h**

```
#ifndef PROJECT_H
#define PROJECT_H

#include <QObject>

class WorkArea{
public://attributes
  int latInf = 30;
public://methods
  WorkArea()//Default constructor
  {
  }
  ~WorkArea();
};


class Project : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public: //attributes
  int lat = 20;
  WorkArea* workArea;
public: //methods
  explicit Project(QObject *parent = nullptr);
signals:
public slots:
};


#endif // PROJECT_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "ui/mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include "project.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Project* pj;

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w( 0 , pj);
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**mainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent, Project *project) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    try
    {
      qDebug() << "Project latInf" << project->lat << "\n"; // works fine
      qDebug()<< "Project lowLeft: " << project->workArea->latInf << "\n" ; // crashes
    }
    catch(std::exception &ex)
    {
      qDebug() << ex.what() ;

    }
    catch (...)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: project.cpp????

Comment: where do you create workArea?, for example `workArea = new WorkArea;`

Comment: #include "project.h"

Project::Project(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

Comment: change `Project::Project(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) { }` to `Project::Project(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) { workArea = new WorkArea; }`

Comment: workArea is a pointer, it does not create a WorkArea object, it can only store the memory address of a WorkArea object

Comment: and change `Project* pj;` to `Project* pj = new Project;`, similar history

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ pointer to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371608/c-pointer-to-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was it. Thanks @eyllanesc. I forgot to create workArea. I though just instanciting it as an attribute in Project was fine, but I had to fill that memory space in the constructor of project.

**project.h**

```
#ifndef PROJECT_H
#define PROJECT_H

#include <QObject>

class WorkArea{
public://attributes
  int latInf = 30;
public://methods
  WorkArea()//Default constructor
  {
  }
  ~WorkArea();
};


class Project : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public: //attributes
  int lat = 20;
  WorkArea* workArea;
public: //methods
  explicit Project(QObject *parent = nullptr){
    workArea = new WorkArea;
  }
signals:
public slots:
};


#endif // PROJECT_H
```

Comment: As a general rule, for efficiency, you probably want to use the initialization list rather than the constructor body.